# Flutter new behavior: channel sent a message from native to Flutter on a non-platform thread

Tags: flutter, xcode, ios-multithreading

MacOS Sonoma 14.0, iOS 17.0, Xcode 15. App deploys to phone. Press a certain button on the app and it craters with a message that I've just started seeing and have no idea how to address.

"[VERBOSE-2:shell.cc(1004)] The 'dev.fluttercommunity.plus/sensors/accelerometer' channel sent a message from native to Flutter on a non-platform thread. Platform channel messages must be sent on the platform thread. Failure to do so may result in data loss or crashes, and must be fixed in the plugin or application code creating that channel."

"[VERBOSE-2:shell.cc(1004)] The 'dev.fluttercommunity.plus/sensors/gyroscope' channel sent a message from native to Flutter on a non-platform thread. Platform channel messages must be sent on the platform thread. Failure to do so may result in data loss or crashes, and must be fixed in the plugin or application code creating that channel."

Downloading darwin-arm64/font-subset tools...                       79ms
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.13.6, on macOS 14.0 23A344 darwin-arm64, locale en-US)
• Flutter version 3.13.6 on channel stable at /Users/wjmetcalfiii/Downloads/flutter
• Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
• Framework revision ead455963c (2 weeks ago), 2023-09-26 18:28:17 -0700
• Engine revision a794cf2681
• Dart version 3.1.3
• DevTools version 2.25.0

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
• Android SDK at /Users/wjmetcalfiii/Library/Android/sdk
• Platform android-34, build-tools 34.0.0
• Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home/bin/java
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.6+0-17.0.6b829.9-10027231)
• All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 15.0)
• Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
• Build 15A240d
• CocoaPods version 1.13.0

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
• Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2022.3)
• Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
• Flutter plugin can be installed from:
 https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
• Dart plugin can be installed from:
 https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.6+0-17.0.6b829.9-10027231)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.82.0)
• VS Code at /Users/wjmetcalfiii/Downloads/Visual Studio Code 2.app/Contents
• Flutter extension version 3.72.0

[✓] VS Code (version 1.81.1)
• VS Code at /Users/wjmetcalfiii/Downloads/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
• Flutter extension version 3.72.0

[✓] Connected device (3 available)
• William’s iPhone (mobile) • 00008120-000C4C3111A2201E • ios            • iOS 17.0.3 21A360
• macOS (desktop)           • macos                     • darwin-arm64   • macOS 14.0 23A344 darwin-arm64
• Chrome (web)              • chrome                    • web-javascript • Google Chrome 117.0.5938.149

[✓] Network resources
• All expected network resources are available.

I'm gob smacked on this one. Was not realizing I was going to have to get into the threading model so quickly. Others are reporting the same thing. Very happy to see there is an ios-multithreading tag, so hey, fingers crossed.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: For clarity: are other people experiencing this behavior with these latest releases and what are their workaround(s)?

Comment: @wjmetcalfiii same here, seems like it should be fixed on the plugins' side.

Comment: I've encountered the same error, any solution?

Comment: Same with the https://pub.dev/packages/nfc_manager package...

[ERROR:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(1015)] The 'plugins.flutter.io/nfc_manager' channel sent a message from native to Flutter on a non-platform thread. Platform channel messages must be sent on the platform thread. Failure to do so may result in data loss or crashes, and must be fixed in the plugin or application code creating that channel.
See https://docs.flutter.dev/platform-integration/platform-channels#channels-and-platform-threading for more information.